# I need to find the distance between the element and the bottom of the browser window

Tags: jquery

I need to find the distance between the element and the bottom of the browser window.

When I select the element, and the distance between the element and the bottom of the browser window is smaller than 50px, I want to make the window scroll automatically.

Any ideas? I'd prefer to use jQuery.

Comment: So you want to find the distance between the *bottom* of the element and the bottom of the page?

Answer (score 36):

Unlike other systems coordinates in browser is from top to bottom, it means top of the browser is y=0.

There is two DOM element property for getting position of an element on the page. The properties are `element.offsetTop` and `element.offsetHeight`

You can calculate the space between your element and bottom of the page by calculating `element.offsetTop` and `window.innerHeight`.

```
var space = window.innerHeight - element.offsetTop
```

if you want to calculate space between bottom of your element and bottom of the window then you need to add your element height too.

```
var space = window.innerHeight - element.offsetTop + element.offsetHeight
```

This calculation is sometimes necessary. Think you have percent based positioning and you want to know position of your element by pixels to do something. For example you have a div positioned like this:

```
div{
    width:300px;
    height:16.2%;
    position:absolute;
    top: 48.11%;
    border:3px dotted black;
}
```

Then you want to know when the div is close to browser window to change it's color:

```
var div = document.querySelector('div'),
    space = innerHeight - div.offsetTop + div.offsetHeight;

 window.onresize = function(){
    space = innerHeight - div.offsetTop + div.offsetHeight;
    if(space < 200){
        div.style.background = 'blue';
    }
};
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VwZKc/)

Comment: @fogsy - fiddle works for me in Chrome using Version 35.0.1916.114

Comment: @Mohsen Brackets please sir! var space = window.innerHeight - (element.offsetTop + element.offsetHeight); And a jQuery equivalent: var space = jQuery(window).height() - (element.offset().top + element.outerHeight());

Comment: @CharlesRobertson um, no, you don't need to use brackets when adding/subtracting...

Comment: I think for bottom calculations this should be `- element.offsetHeight` instead of `+ element.offsetHeight`

Answer (score 22):

Using `element.getBoundingClientRect()` is a nice straight forward way to get the offset of the bottom of the element which is relative to the viewport rather than the document. Then you can just subtract this value from `window.innerHeight` to calculate the remaining space between the element and the bottom of the browser window (viewport). Like in the example below:

```js
var element = document.querySelector('.inner');

window.onscroll = function() {
    var domRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    var spaceBelow = window.innerHeight - domRect.bottom;
    
    element.style.background = (spaceBelow < 50 ? 'blue' : 'transparent');
};
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}

.outer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  border: 1px dashed green;
  width: 95%;
  height: 80px;
}

.inner {
    width:300px;
    height:16.2%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 48.11%;
    border:3px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

If you prefer to use jQuery then alternatively the following code should also work:

```
var spaceBelow = $(window).height() - $('.inner')[0].getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
```

Comment: Will your solution calculate distance between the nested element the bottom of browser?
Also how can it work if we want to calculate distance between the bottom of the browser and the bottom point of the nested item? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @NewTechLover Yes, that's exactly what it does. Just as the question was asking

Comment: Thank you for being a bit more recent than the others