# Setting a max-height of page-height for a dropdown

Tags: javascript, css

Say you have a dropdown with a lot of options that overflow the page height. I know I can use `overflow: auto` to make it scroll, but only if I set it a `max-height`. How do I set a max-height that ensures the element won't overflow the browser window?

[Like in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBvoL.png)

The left is what it's like now. Dropdown overflows page. The right is what it should be like -- the dropdown is resized to be height of just under the page height.

I've tried setting `max-height` to different values like `45vh` since the dropdown is about halfway down the page, but this needs to fit all types of screen sizes so isn't flexible enough.

CSS solutions preferred in this case.

Comment: can you provide link?

Comment: share your code what you have tried so far.

Comment: where is your code share fiddle

Comment: Can't share the code as the codebase is private unfortunately. What I've tried so far is the `max-height: 45vh` with `overflow: auto`, which works on desktop but not for other screen sizes like mobile.

Comment: without your code example, it's hard to guess the issue, i'd throw max height with percentage `max-height: x%` most likely what you're after.

Comment: is your sidebar is fixed?. if yes then you can set max-height: 100%;top;0;overflow-y:auto;
otherwise max-height : 100vh will work fine.

Comment: Can you use flexbox? If yes I have an idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the current distance between the dropdown and the bottom of the page (https://stackoverflow.com/a/7656176/5370933) and append styles with this value.

```
.myDropdown {
  max-height: myDistance;
  overflow: scroll
}
```

I think something like that could works. But you will have to use some JS to get the distance dynamically (depend on the user screen and/or user scroll before the dropdown opening...)

Comment: I agree that this the _straightforward way_ of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly the layout of your web page, the dropdown is the last  element (well maybe) in the page.

What you could do is, first, **add this lines to your main page container**:

```css
#page {
  min-height: 100vh; /* Or the value you like most */
}
```

Now we have access to the **full height** of the document.

---

Next, you can simply use flexbox's `space-between` or `space-around` value to keep the dropdown on the bottom of the page (like footers).

But now, you want a little space between the end of the page and the dropdown. Simply add a `margin-bottom` and its done.

---

Now be aware that, I understand that there may be a footer or something below the dropdown. You can implement this solution in any container.

---

This isn't a bug-free solution, but it doesn't require javascript.

---

Here is a working example.

```js
function _test_add(){
  document.getElementById("dropdown").innerHTML += "<li>Item</li>";
}
```

```css
#page {
  min-height:100vh;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#addbtn {
  margin:0 auto;
}


/*
 * Fictif Content
 */
#main-content {
  height: 50vh;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  background-color:gray;
}

#dropdown {
  min-height: 8em;
  max-height: 18em;
  background-color:#f1f1f1;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-bottom:4em;
  border: solid black 2px;
}

#dropdown li {
  padding:1em;
}

#dropdown li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #fafafa;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
    <div id="main-content">
        Main Content
    </div>
    
    <button id="addbtn" onclick="_test_add()">[TEST] Add items in dropdown</button>
    
    <ul id="dropdown">
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```